# Tabtastic, javascript component ... how to addeventlistener to capture tab click

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am using a 3rd party javascript component called Tabtastic http://phrogz.net/js/tabtastic/index.html that builds tab systems.

How do you *properly* capture tab mouseevents?

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you don't. There is no `mouseevent api` documented.

Comment: snowblind, I have not found any documentation ... if you did could you share the link.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd OK. But I suggest using a more common ui framework i.e:`JqueryUI`

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Could you please accept the answer or vote up at least?

Comment: I'm sorry but it does not answer the question ... the question is how to, which may require a hack into the component. The question is about the 'best practice' for injecting a mouseevent listener into the tabtastic framework ... but I do appreciate your response.